# What about a Plane-Train?

Tags: experimental-aircraft, ground-effect

The Shanghai Maglev Train's max speed is 267 mph. Could a plane be made to follow a rail, surface area provided, if not an existing rail to travel along? How much faster could the heavily modified train/plane travel?

The plane is "on rail, not touching the track while following it, not over water but over a track made of concrete" or less.

Another way to ask, is how much would a very large cruise missile shaped vehicle benefit from using ground effect (possibly using curved surface area or rail to follow) verses not? Because the the rail is not directly supporting the wight of the vehicle, at least directly, how sturdy would that rail need to be? When done over water, the water is displaced by the air pressure under the ground effect plane.

Comment: I would think that if you are going to rely on the infrastructure of a rail system you might as well get rid of the drag of the wings.  267 is plenty fast, if you want faster go in an airplane.  I just don't see any advantages to the sort of hybrid you have loosely described.  But go ahead, convince me!  ;)

Comment: When I first read the quesiton, I tought you wanted to revive the [aerotrain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%C3%A9rotrain), but then I realize you just want to make an hovercraft or a GEV. I fail to understand how different from an hovercraft your vehicle would be.

Comment: So, you want to take a mode of transport that has the fundamental property that it stays on the ground and combine it with another mode of transport whose fundamental property is that is does **not** stay on the ground. I think we can see why this idea hasn't made progress before.

Comment: The Maglev does *not*, in fact, stay on the ground. It levitates because of magnetism. Also, planes do not really go any faster than the Maglev while they are close to the ground, both for reasons of avoiding noise and because the high air pressure compared to FL400 does put more stress on the airframe. So, uh, your idea basically has been done, at least as close as is reasonable. (Also note that altitude equals safety in aviation, being close to the ground gives you less room for maneuvering and an engine failure or similar has much more impact than at higher altitudes.)

Comment: The newest train under construction in Japan will reach approx 375 mph (603 kph).

Comment: If the vehicle must follow tracks, then it is a train, regardless of whether it is in contact with the track or hovering a few inches above it. Planes, even ones that can only fly in ground effect, do not have tracks.

Comment: "How sturdy would that rail need to be?" If it's a "cruise missile shaped vehicle in ground effect" then it doesn't need a rail at all because it's not touching the ground when moving, so the answer to that part is "tissue paper will suffice". I'm more than a bit confused by your proposal, could you expand on your question to give a better idea of what you're after?

Comment: @FreeMan I updated it. Water or not the surface area will still take some of weight of the plane from the air cushion but how much in comparison to a vehicles weight directly applied to the ground through physical contact..

Comment: @StephenS Not yet they don't. It is still a plane if it is dependent on air to travel as a ground effect plane does, it also depends on a relatively flat surface, and on land it would need to be a track. The plane could be magnetically driven externally not to need an engine, like a rail-gun and the ground effect plane would be the bullet.

Comment: @Justintimeforfun Given your last edits, I think you should also emphasize how your vehicle differ from the [aerotrain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%C3%A9rotrain) (on rail, not touching the track while following it, not over water but over a track made of concrete)

Comment: @ManuH how is that?

Comment: Are you asking about [ground effect trains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ground_effect_train)?

Comment: @Justintimeforfun did you read the content linked in comments (not only mine)?

Comment: @TerranSwett no and yes but more towards just modifying a plane to behave like a train. With the ability to pull up if needed.

Answer (score 7):

The first issue with airplanes is they are *stupendously, freakishly* light.  Any random [American freight diesel](https://trains-and-locomotives.fandom.com/wiki/GE_ES44AC) locomotive weighs more than a 747-400.  **Trains rely on this mass to provide the downforce to keep them engaged to the railhead**.

So your vehicle would need to do something to replace this downforce; for instance have a tubular or I-beam rail which allows the train to grab the bottom of the rail; expect switches and special work to be complicated at that point, shifting an entire track instead of just small parts of it.

So while unloading weight off the rail only makes matters worse for track design, **you're also paying for that lift with induced drag**. In other words you're using a great deal more fuel (or electricity) to unload weight off the rail, when the rail really doesn't mind bearing weight.

*In fact from an aviation perspective, the "induced drag" on a train can be approximated to zero, thanks to Mr. Babbitt (Mr. Timken's idea is worse for drag but better for reliability).*

That's why *good ole fashioned railroad* just keeps winning the high-speed race (or coming too close to matter). The [exact TGV train that ran 357 mph](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjJz4jgopHrAhXXB80KHRLoCXAQwqsBMAF6BAgNEAo&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DdAeYGRxiz5w&usg=AOvVaw2UW3aEhiz9-BJfpqUZrlXm) could be dropped onto a NYC subway branch in Brooklyn, interchange onto LIRR, come into Penn Station and the Amtrak Corridor, through the freight rail system to Detroit and run on Woodward Avenue Q-line, then to Long Beach CA and run on the Blue Line.  The only thing I'm arm-waving is power supply, and curve and platform clearances on NYCTA.  In fact, in 1993 Amtrak dragged an X2000 and ICE high-speed trainset all over America behind diesels. No wheel modification needed.

So while your idea has merit... once you get out the sharp pencil and really start optimizing for performance, you will find it best to forget wings and load full weight on the rail, and further, to optimize for Plain Old Railroad Track so you can just use existing rails to get downtown.  Going with a wack-a-doodle guideway *doesn't buy you much*, and makes getting downtown a mega-project of biblical proportion  all its own. [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XpressWest):

> The city of Victorville was selected as the location for the westernmost terminal since extending the train line farther into the Los Angeles basin through the Cajon Pass would be prohibitively expensive.

*/facepalm... Cajon Pass is not a challenging hill for HSR. If they can't even handle that, they sure aren't getting into L.A. proper where all the connecting trains are.  And L.A. is a piece of cake compared to a dense, old city like Paris or even Boston.  This: This is the folly of a wack-a-doodle guideway.  They finally retreated from that to a standard railroad design, so they could come downtown on shared rails.*

Comment: I am not worried about max efficiency as far as the vehicle, so much as max efficiency for the speed of it; to have a plane to travel like a train to achieve higher speeds verses normal cargo or passenger flight or train ride. Less efficient than a train, but more efficient than normal cargo flight.

Comment: If I could make my question read like your answer. Great work!

Comment: To elaborate on your last point, if you have a vehicle with wings following the railway, you need a much wider right of way.  You also need to rebuild all multiple track sections of your railroad to provide sufficient clearance for vehicles going in opposite directions, and you have to worry about intruding cows, deer, humans, &c being struck by the wings.  As pointed out, a diesel locomotive is a LOT sturdier than an airplane wing.

Comment: The Amtrak ICE did, in fact, have its wheels replaced because American rail profiles differ from German ones.